# Why can I not see close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, user-interface

Having sked [this question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/29156/does-lactose-intolerance-improve-by-refraining-then-partaking-of-dairy-products) I was told that there was a close vote due to lack of research (to which I have responded by edit) but I am unable to see any close vote on the page.

Is this due to lack of reputation votes ?

On other sites I am able to see close votes on all questions due to rep but I imagined that I would be able to see close votes on my own questions even if I was lacking in rep votes for other purposes.

Comment: You have over 10K rep on three other sites, which gives you access to moderator tools on those sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 250 rep to see close votes.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: Thank you kindly.